# Migrating MantisBT 1.1.2 to JIRA 5.1.1

Tags: jira, mantis

I have an existing issue tracker system, MantisBT using very old version 1.1.2 (using MySql 5.0) and I have a requirement to migrate it to another issue tracker system JIRA using latest 5.1.1 version.

Although JIRA supports MantisBT issue migration, it only supports from MantisBT version 1.1.8 onward. And I am stuck!!!

I tried to upgrade MantisBT to latest 1.2.11 (using MySql 5.5) by doing the following steps:
- export my old MantisBT MySQL database into a sql file.
- import this sql file into MySql 5.5 
- when I tried to access the new MantisBT login page, I faced the following error:

```
APPLICATION ERROR #401 
Database query failed. Error received from database was #126: Incorrect key file for table '.\bugtracker\mantis_config_table'; try to repair it for the query: SELECT config_id, user_id, project_id, type, value, access_reqd FROM mantis_config_table.
```

Anyone has any experience in doing the above?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your database is broken. Have you tried repairing it? [MySQL REPAIR TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)

Comment: Yes, I did using the sql command "repair table mantis_config_table" but failed to repair.